# Angular 8 Subject doesnt trigger on Event

Tags: rxjs, angular8

Im trying to listen to a click Event in one Component, after the click a Function from a service gets called.

Component that listens to the click:

```
  searchForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private search: SearchService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
      'search': new FormControl(null)
    })
    this.search.searchEvent.subscribe({ // For testing purposes
      next: (searchResponse) => {
        console.log(searchResponse)
      }
    })
  }

  onSearch(){
    this.search.onSearch(this.searchForm)
  }
```

The Service:

```
  subscription: Subscription;
  searchEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: Router) {
  }

  onSearch(searchForm: FormGroup){
    if(searchForm.controls['search'].value){
      this.http.post(URL, searchForm.controls['search'].value).subscribe(searchResponse => {
        this.searchEvent.next(searchResponse)
      })

      this.route.navigate(['/company-search'])
    }
    this.subscription = searchForm.controls['search'].valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      if(!val){
        this.route.navigate(['/'])
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    })
  }
```

Now i have another component that needs the SearchResponse from the http Request

```
  searchResponse: object[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private search: SearchService) {
    this.searchResponse = [];
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription = this.search.searchEvent.subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

The Problem I have is that when a click happens the next function get called but only in the component that listens to the click. The Subscription in the Component that needs the SearchResponse doesnt log the message from the next event but the one in the first Component does.

PS.
I have to do it with a service because in the parent html im using a router outlet

Comment: Maybe you list `SearchService` in your components' `providers` arrays?

Comment: Nope, already done

Comment: The point is, you _shouldn't_. If `SearchService` is listed in `providers` in different places, then it's no longer a singleton. It's possible that the two components access different instances of `SearchService` class.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you for your help